# Shuffle Dask array chunks from hdf5 file

Tags: arrays, dask, h5py

I have a very large array stored in an hdf5 file. I am trying to load it and manage it as a Dask array.

At the moment my challenge is that i need to shuffle this array time to time in a process, this is a challenge by itself to shuffle an array bigger than memory.

So what i am trying to do without success is to shuffle the dask array chunks.

```
#Prepare data
f=h5py.File('Data.hdf5')
dset = f['/Data']
dk_array = da.from_array(dset, chunks=dset.chunks)
```

So given the context above how can i shuffle the chunks?

Comment: Could you be more specific in what you want to achieve: how would you shuffle, and to what end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your array is tabular in nature then you might consider adding a column of random data (see `da.concatenate` and `da.random`), turning it into a dask.dataframe, and setting that column as the index.

As a warning, this will be somewhat slow as it will need to do an on-disk shuffle.

Comment: Thanks, that will help. Cheers.